# where to keep build snapshots in svn

Tags: svn, version-control, build

We need to archive our project's build output (in our case, a single executable file of approx 1MB in size) in a controlled manner.

**NOTE:** The practical upshot of this, is that for any released build output, I need to archive an immutable copy of it indefinitely. (e.g. if we build from r993, r1014, r1205, and r1293 of our source tree, I need to keep one build output for each.)

It's natural for us to use Subversion for this because we have a server running. What's unnatural is where to put the build output.

1. **Check into an area of the source tree** --> not good, because it complicates updates/merges/etc.
2. **Create a special area in the repository associated with the source tree** e.g.:

   ```
   project-foo/
     branches/
     tags/
     trunk/
     build/        <-- released executables go here
                   (along with metadata containing source references)
   ```

   We really don't need branches or tags for the executable output; I just need a place that's an immutable snapshot which I can make reference to (in SVN's case, by path and rev #)
3. **Create a special area in the repository loosely associated with the source tree** e.g.:

   ```
   project-foo/
     branches/
     tags/
     trunk/
   project-foo-build/          <-- released executables go into a subdir:
     branches/
     tags/
     trunk/
   ```
4. **Use another program rather than SVN.** ??? Whatever this is, it needs to support the ideas of

   - immutable data
   - metadata associated with the data
   - several versions of the same kind of thing (e.g. the build executable for project foo)

Any suggestions?

I'm leaning toward idea #2, but wanted to step back and get a better sense of the various advantages/disadvantages.

---

*We need to do this because we need to maintain the *exact* build output that was used under certain circumstances. This is embedded code loaded into hardware. Ideally the build output is a repeatable function of the source tree, so if you build twice with the same source tree, it produces the same output. Unfortunately there's risk to this not being the case e.g. as compilers or other build tools are updated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to store the *actual* files in the Subversion repository to keep track of them with a reasonable degree of confidence. What you can do is create the output file(s), compute a hash (eg. SHA1) of the file contents, and then store the filename and hash value in the repository.

As long as your output file storage is backed up to at least the same level as your Subversion repository so you don't lose them, you can be certain (within a reasonable degree) that the given file(s) were the output generated by the build at the time you recorded the hash.

Comment: Good idea... That still doesn't solve the archiving, though. I need to archive *all* released versions.

Comment: @Jason S: You could store the build output files on a file server in a directory named after the Subversion revision number, eg. `\product\releases\r1293\output.zip` So your release process might be: (1) Check out the code, (2) Build the code, (3) Hash the output file(s), (4) Update a text file in Subversion that holds the release file hashes, (5) Commit that file, (6) Copy the output files to the directory named after the revision created in (5). Of course you'd do this on a release branch to avoid somebody checking in new code between (1) and (5) (but also check that hasn't happened).

Comment: OK. Is there any software that facilitates immutable archives? While I like the link to outside files that's achieved by hashing, I really get nervous about providing this storage itself. (e.g. what if there is an incorrect hash? someone has to check for this + find it)

Answer (score 1):

Several of your options would work just fine, but I would vote for #4.

My company also creates and releases embedded SW packages, and we require storage of the actual binaries we deliver (along with build documentation, various output file formats, etc...) in addition to tagging the SW revision in the repository.

I agree with Greg Hewgill's response regarding placing them on a file server in a distinct directory. If, on the other hand, you are looking for a more complete SCM tool, [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is a great open-source option. Redmine provides SVN (or Hg, Git, etc...) bindings, issue tracking, file management, and so on. It's not just a file repository, but a more complete SCM tool.

Additionally, wikipedia has a [comprehensive list of SCM tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_project_management_software), many of which can be configured easily to act as a deliverable storage tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the build, `svn add` the binaries to your working copy, and then tag *directly from your working copy*:

```
build.bat
svn add bin\*
svn cp . http://example.com/svn/myproject/tags/x.y -m "tagging release x.y"
svn revert -R .
```

That way the binaries appear in your release tags, but never in trunk.

Note the `svn revert` at the end. This is necessary because `svn status` will still show the changes made by `svn add`. You don't want those changes in trunk.

Answer (score 0):

As you say it's unnatural to use SVN for build products, because good practise is to have only source code in your repository. You would better name the build output without ambiguities (project-branch-revision), named by your build process, and archive the build output in a classic manner (file server).

Comment: -1: I never said it was unnatural to use SVN for build products. I said it was unnatural to figure out where to put them. As far as alternatives to SVN, I'm open to them, but just saying "file server" really doesn't help much.